# Why are pool.map() and map() returning varying results?

Tags: python, group-by, multiprocessing, python-itertools, pool

I have the following program :

```
import string
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mp

def test(word_list):
    return list(map(lambda xy: (xy[0], len(list(xy[1]))),
        itertools.groupby(sorted(word_list))))

def f(x):
    return (x[0], len(list(x[1])))

def test_parallel(word_list):
    w = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(w)
    return (pool.map(f, itertools.groupby(sorted(word_list))))

def main():
    test_list = ["test", "test", "test", "this", "this", "that"]

    print(test(test_list))
    print(test_parallel(test_list))

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is :

```
[('test', 3), ('that', 1), ('this', 2)]
[('test', 0), ('that', 0), ('this', 1)]
```

The first line is the expected and correct result. My question is, why isn't pool.map() returning the same results as map()?

Also, I'm aware a 6 item list isn't the perfect case for multiprocessing. This is simply a demonstration of the issue I am having while implementing in a larger application.

I'm using Python 3.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby()` returns *iterators* per group, and these are *not independent* from the underlying iterator passed in. You can't independently iterate over these groups in parallel; any preceding group will be prematurely ended the moment you access the next.

`pool.map()` will try to read all of the `groupby()` iterator results to send those results to separate functions; merely trying to get a second group will cause the first to be empty.

You can see the same result without `pool.map()` simply by iterating to the next result from `groupby()`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> word_list = ["test", "test", "test", "this", "this", "that"]
>>> iterator = groupby(sorted(word_list))
>>> first = next(iterator)
>>> next(first[1])
'test'
>>> second = next(iterator)
>>> list(first[1])
[]
```

The remainder of the first group is 'empty' because the second group has been requested.

This is clearly [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.

You'd have to 'materialise' each group *before* sending it to the the function:

```
return pool.map(lambda kg: f((k[0], list(kg[1]))), itertools.groupby(sorted(word_list)))
```

or

```
return pool.map(f, (
    (key, list(group)) for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(word_list))))
```

where the generator expression takes care of the materialising as `pool.map()` iterates.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you for pointing this out to me!
I think I'd have a problem pickling the lambda though.

Comment: @Surtr: right; added a generator expression version to mitigate that. That at least keeps the materialisation lazy.

Comment: Both great answers - I especially appreciate the lack of condescension. I'm giving you Best Answer because yours came through first. Thanks @smarx for an equally great answer.

Answer (score 3):

From https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
>   iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the
>   groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.
>   So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list:
>
> ```
> groups = []
> uniquekeys = []
> data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
> for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
>     groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
>     uniquekeys.append(k)
> ```

I think the issue here is that `Pool.map` tries to chop up its input, and in doing so, it iterates through the result of `groupby`, which effectively skips over the elements from all but the last group.

One fix for your code would be to use something like `[(k, list(v)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(word_list))]`, but I don't know how applicable that is to your real-world use case.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. Will try your suggested workaround.